# How to get the index of a parent of the item from where the click event was triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have the code in this pen : http://codepen.io/Cristian_N/pen/PPbBde?editors=101

To explain what I did there, I added a button that would append a fieldset when it was clicked.

Whithin that fieldset ( both the original and the appended one ) there is also a button that appends an input to a div that is whithin the fieldset.

What I want to do is this: when I add multiple input elements, those input elements should get the index number of the parent fieldset, while incrementing the operations number. I managed the incrementing of the operations number part. Is there any way I can make it get the fieldset index number with javascript/jquery?

My html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-10 columns large-centered">
        <form id="client-details" class="" method="post" action="action-write.php">
            <div id="client-details-form">
                <label>First Name
                    <input type="text" name="clients[0][firstName]">
                </label>

                <label>Last Name
                    <input type="text" name="clients[0][lastName]">
                </label>

                <label>Date
                    <input type="text" name="clients[0][created]" value="20-sept-2015">
                </label>

                <fieldset class="eq-grup-0">
                    <legend>Equipment</legend>

                    <label>
                        <input type="text" name="clients[0][equipment][0][name]">
                    </label>

                    <div class="op-field">
                        <div class="row collapse">
                            <div class="small-2 columns">
                                <span class="prefix">Operatiune</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="small-6 columns">
                                <input type="text" name="clients[0][equipment][0][operations][0][name]">
                            </div>
                            <div class="small-3 columns">
                                <span class=" postfix add-op" id="add-op">Adauga Operatiune</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="button small" id="add-eq-group">Add Eq</span>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
var i = $('#client-details fieldset').size();

var k = $('.op-to-be-removed', $(this).parent('fieldset')).index();

$("#client-details-form").on("click", "#add-eq-group", function(){ 
    $("#client-details-form").append('<fieldset class="eq-to-be-removed eq-grup-' + i + '"><legend>Equipment</legend><label><input  type="text"name="clients[<?php echo $c; ?>][equipment][' + i + '][name]"></label><div class="op-field"><div class="row collapse"><div class="small-2 columns"><span class="prefix">Operatiune</span></div><div class="small-6 columns"><input type="text" name="clients[<?php echo $c; ?>][equipment][' + i + '][operations][0][name]"></div><div class="small-3 columns"><span class=" postfix add-op" id="add-op">Adauga Operatiune</span></div></div></div><span class="button small remove_eq">Remove Eq</span></fieldset>');
    i++; 
});

$("#client-details-form").on("click", ".remove_eq", function(){
    if( i > 0 ) {
        $(this).closest(".eq-to-be-removed").remove();
        i--;
    }
});

$("#client-details-form").on("click", "#add-op", function() {
    var j = $('.op-to-be-removed', $(this).closest('.op-field')).size() + 1;

    $(this).closest(".op-field").append('<div class="row collapse op-to-be-removed"><div class="small-2 columns"><span class="prefix">Operatiune</span></div><div class="small-6 columns"><input type="text" name="clients[<?php echo $c; ?>][equipment][' + k + '][operations][' + j + '][name]"></div><div class="small-3 columns"><span class="postfix remove_op">Sterge</span></div></div>');
    j++;
});

$("#client-details-form").on("click", ".remove_op", function(){
    if( j > 1 ) {
        $(this).closest(".op-to-be-removed").remove();
        j--;
    }
});
```

Comment: (If you can) give us an example describe _those input elements should get the index number of the parent fieldset, while incrementing the operations number_.

Comment: Something like **[this](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/WQRNpy?editors=101)**?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao something like that. I managed to figure it out in the meantime and updated the original pen with the solution [here](http://codepen.io/Cristian_N/pen/PPbBde). I used this `var k = $($(this).closest('fieldset')).index();` for `k`

Comment: You can post it as a solution then and accept it as answer so that others find it useful.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out in the meantime and updated the original pen with the solution [here](http://codepen.io/Cristian_N/pen/PPbBde). I used this `var k = $($(this).closest('fieldset')).index();` for `k`